# aggregated sum of sales data in interval of 5 minutes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have sales data which came in every minutes, I want to sum of aggregated data at the interval of 5 minutes in MySQL query, I tried various way but not got success.
My sales date time have the below format

```
format(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)
```

```
 timestamp               sales

2021-03-10 13:59:49        1.5

2021-03-10 13:59:51        2.5

2021-03-10 14:03:23        2.5

2021-03-10 16:15:16        4.6

2021-03-10 16:15:18        2.6

2021-03-10 16:18:50        8.5

2021-03-10 16:22:21        2.6

2021-03-10 16:25:53        8.2

2021-03-10 16:29:24        9.5
```

Please help.

Comment: You probably want to check that format :)

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Pythonsguru please share some sample.

Comment: @AmitVerma Please check sample data

Answer (score 1):

By doing some more efforts I got this solution this is working for me.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(300 * FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/300)) AS start_time, SUM(sales) as Sales
FROM db_name.table_name
where timestamp between '2021-07-02 06:00:01' and '2021-07-03 06:00:00'
GROUP BY start_time;
```